# Problem (1) 1.A of Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler: Multiplicative Inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

My textbook, *Linear Algebra Done Right, Third Edition*, by Axler, has the following problem:

> Suppose $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, not both $0$. Find real numbers $c$ and $d$ such that
>
> $$\dfrac{1}{(a + bi)} = c + di.$$

This is effectively finding the multiplicative inverse $\beta = c + di$:

> **multiplicative inverse**
>
> for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\alpha \not= 0$, there exists a unique $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\alpha \beta = 1$.

However, I'm struggling to see how this is done.

I found the following solution online:

> Because $(a + bi)(a - bi) = a^2 + b^2$, one has
>
> $$\dfrac{1}{a + bi} = \dfrac{a - bi}{a^2 + b^2}$$
>
> Hence
>
> $$c = \dfrac{a}{a^2 + b^2}, \ \ d = -\dfrac{b}{a^2 + b^2}$$

However, I don't see how $c = \dfrac{a}{a^2 + b^2}, \ \ d = -\dfrac{b}{a^2 + b^2}$ follows from $\dfrac{1}{a + bi} = \dfrac{a - bi}{a^2 + b^2}$?

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: Compare the real part and the imaginary part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{a + bi} & = \frac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2} \\
& = \frac{a}{a^2+b^2} + \frac{-bi}{a^2+b^2} \\
& = \frac{a}{a^2+b^2} + \left(\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2}\right)i
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Consider the solution of what $c$ and $d$ are in the original equation of

$$\frac{1}{(a + bi)} = c + di \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Comparing the real & imaginary parts as suggested in the question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3489660/problem-1-1-a-of-linear-algebra-done-right-by-axler-multiplicative-inverse/3489662#comment7175648_3489660) (since $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, then $\frac{a}{a^2 + b^2}$ and $\frac{-b}{a^2 + b^2}$ are also both real values), gives the solution you're asking about, i.e., that

$$c = \frac{a}{a^2 + b^2}, \ \ d = -\frac{b}{a^2 + b^2} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$